# How to keep a float or something to keep subtracting in python?

Tags: python

I wonder how to keep the following to keep subtracting to get a total in the following python script -

```
num = input ("How many additional items do you have?: ")
num = int(num)
#Entering additional items to purchase
for i in range (0,num):
    item=input("Enter price for additional items: ")
    amount2=float(amount)-float(item)
print("Debit card balance is: ", amount2)
```

It seems to subtract the first item, but say when I run the code and say I have 3 more items, it just subtracts the first, and does something to the rest not know how to keep it going to subtract all the items entered.

Comment: Where is amount coming from? - it is undefined for the range you've provided.

Comment: Your most recent edit only obscures the code- there isn't an indented block and this will throw a SyntaxError.

Comment: I suggested an edit that will make the code readable, if that solves the problem then I have nothing to say.

Comment: Just for pathological need, the one-liner for calculating the remaining balance, if initial balance is `amount` and already converted to `float`: `amount -= sum(float(input("Enter price for additional items: ")) for _ in range(num))`